# Extract data from javascript chart

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, chart.js

I'm trying to start a project regarding a stock trading tool. I would like to extract data from an existing stock chart online. However, I thought it would be easy as parsing HTML code, but I noticed that most of them are made of javascript which I am not familiar with.

I'll be using python 3.4 for this project.

Any starting ideas would be deeply appreciated!

Cheers!